# The correct way to generate list of articles using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

My first question here in SO :). I actually need to load data in the form of array of objects like this:

```
var data = [
{
    'id': '1',
    'firstName': 'Megan',
    'lastName': 'Fox',
    'picture': 'images/01.jpg',
    'bio': 'bla bla bla bla.'
},
{
    'id': '2',
    'firstName': 'Robert',
    'lastName': 'Pattinson',
    'picture': 'images/02.jpg',
    'bio': 'bli bli bli bli.'
}
```

Then I would like to display the data in HTML using this structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <article>
        <header>
            <h2>[firstName 1 here]<h2>
        </header>
        <section>
            <p>[bio 1 here]</p>
        </section>
    </article>
    <article>
        <header>
            <h2>[firstName 2 here]<h2>
        </header>
        <section>
            <p>[bio 2 here]</p>
        </section>
    </article>
</div>
```

And the JS function I created is below:

```
var loadArtists = function() {
    var $tmpHtml = '';
    for (var artist in artists) {
        var objArtist = artists[artist],
        fullname = objArtist.firstName + ' ' + objArtist.lastName,
        bio = objArtist.bio,
        id = objArtist.id,
        pic = objArtist.picture;

        $tmpHtml += '<article><header data-id="' + id + '"><h2>' + fullname + '</h2></header><section data-id="' + id + '"><div class="imgContainer"><img alt="' + fullname + '" src="' + pic + '" /></div><h2 class="hiddenName">' + fullname + '</h2><p>' + bio + '</p></section></article>'; 
    }

    $('div.wrapper').append($tmpHtml);
};
```

Are those codes good? Or there is (are) better and more elegant way to construct the HTML?

Thanks!

Comment: Check template . Ex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487647/understanding-jquery-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. I ended up using **[Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)** to make my codes better. Thanks to Murali for the jQuery template link which led me to do more research on some of the available HTML template libraries. The reason I did not go for jQuery templates, because its been discontinued and it's not receiving anymore support from the jQuery team.

Comment: Mustache is great. You might also take a look at Handlebars (http://handlebarsjs.com/), which is Mustache-compatible. Want to know the differences? Stack Overflow to the rescue as always: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555820/what-are-the-differences-between-mustache-js-and-handlebars-js

Comment: Yes, I also used Handlebars apparently, so much better way to use HTML templating rather than the conservative way. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

use [jTemplates](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/).

or

format your template string using [string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14062431/1400155)