# Is it necessary to run react project without babel?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

Is it necessary to configure React Project without babel which is a transpiler for JavaScript (turning ES6 into code that runs in your browser) ? or with babel as es6 is necessary to use in React projects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I really need Babel or other transpilers to use ES6 with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030907/do-i-really-need-babel-or-other-transpilers-to-use-es6-with-react)

Answer (score 1):

Well, Babel is not really needed but writing React apps without JSX is not something a sane person would do.

Writing React without Babel is not viable honestly.

Comment: Got it! Thanks alot! :)