# Problems with ES6 spread operator in ReactJS project

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I really need your help!
I've written two versions of react functions. One with the spread operator and the other without and only the version without is working.

Working version:

```
onAddBook() {
  var updatedBooks = this.state.books;
  var finalBook = {
    title: this.state.title
  };
  updatedBooks.push(finalBooks);
  this.setState({
    books: updatedBooks
  });
}
```

Not working:

```
var finalBook = {
  title: this.state.title
}
this.setState({
  books: [...this.state.books, finalBook]
});
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Eva! It's hard to say what might be wrong from this code alone. Could you include your entire component?

Comment: Yes sorry. The error I received: cannot read property title of undefined. Im not home as soon as i get home i will add the entire component thanks (:

Comment: That error doesn't seem related to your use of the spread operator. Your spread version looks correct.

Comment: @EvaCohen Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , this is a requirement for code-related questions. Where exactly do you have 'Not working' code? The error clearly states that there's no `this.state` where you use it. There's no problem with spread, as it was already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone mentioned in the question there is nothing wrong with your spread implementation. Please find the added snippet for that confirmation.

**Primary Check**
Check whether your transpiler supports ES6 with React. If not; try looking in adding one for your project like `babel`. [Check this discussion for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030907/do-i-really-need-babel-or-other-transpilers-to-use-es6-with-react)

**Secondary Check**
Referring to your error `cannot read property title of undefined` could be something related to your `this.state.title` in the code. Either the `title` is undefined in your state or not yet initialised by the time `this.state.title` is called. So please look into the exact line of code where it is breaking to trace the error.

```js
// Without the spread operator
const updatedBooks = [{ title: 'Hi' }, { title: 'Hello' }]
const finalBook = {
  title: 'How'
}
updatedBooks.push(finalBook)
console.log('result without spread:', updatedBooks)


// With Spread operator
const books = [{ title: 'Hi' }, { title: 'Hello' }]
const finalBook2 = {
  title: 'How'
}
console.log('result with spread',[...books, finalBook2])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much OwlyMoly!!