# Serving static files in Express with mustache templating

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mustache, middleware

I'm trying to serve a folder of static mustache files from Express, but can't seem to figure out how to get it working. Say I just have an object of data like

```
{
  a: 'Hello :)'
  b: 'Goodbye :('
}
```

And two files,

`public/a.html`

```
<div>{{a}}</div>
```

`public/b.html`

```
<div>{{b}}</div>
```

How could I get express setup to where it serves any arbitrary number of static html files and replaces the templated parts with just my one big object? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Static files are usually only called *static* when they are not processed in any way before sending to user.

What you're trying to achieve is a typical templating system. You can just follow instructions in the [plugin](https://github.com/bryanburgers/node-mustache-express):

```
var mustacheExpress = require('mustache-express');

// Register '.html' extension with The Mustache Express
app.engine('html', mustacheExpress());

app.set('view engine', 'mustache');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); // you can change '/views' to '/public',
    // but I recommend moving your templates to a directory
    // with no outside access for security reasons

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('a');
});
```

Also consider using [Handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars), it's often more convenient to use than Mustache. You can find a list of differences in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555820/what-are-the-differences-between-mustache-js-and-handlebars-js).

Comment: Yeah I had noticed that plugin when googling earlier, but since there's no documentation I was really confused. What exactly is the `'a'` in `res.render('a')`? I'd like to be able to have an arbitrary number of files in `/views` and have them all rendered using the same data object.

Comment: The `'a'` in `res.render('a')` is the name of your template: `a.html` (without extension). You can pass the same data object to every `render()` call like that: `var data = {a:1,b:2}; res.render('a', data);`

Comment: So how would I also incorporate b into this setup?

Comment: `res.render('b', data);` — the templates are loaded automatically if they are in the `/views` directory with `.html` extension (as configured with the code above)

Comment: Maybe things have changed since you posted your comment "there's no documentation". What documentation are you looking for exactly? I followed the Handlebars Github project link in this answer and found fairly verbose and complete documentation. Maybe give Handlebars another try as it really does abstract away the complexities that Mustache introduces.

Comment: Thank you for this simple answer!

Comment: If you use `app.engine('html', …)` then you have to do `app.set('view engine', 'html')`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `mustachejs` just like `pug` in express by setting `mustache` as `view engine` and defining its working like below code:

```js
//required files
const fs = require("fs")
const mustache = require("mustache")

// To set functioning of mustachejs view engine
app.engine('html', function (filePath, options, callback) { 
    fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, content) {
        if(err)
            return callback(err)        
        var rendered = mustache.to_html(content.toString(),options);
        return callback(null, rendered)
    });
  });

// Setting mustachejs as view engine
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view engine','html');

//rendering example for response
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{        
    res.render('index',{data:'Sample Data'});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I modify zlumer's answer a little bit and the following code works fine for me.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mustacheExpress = require('mustache-express');

app.engine('html', mustacheExpress());

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  const data = {
    hello: 'world',
    foo: 'bar'
  };

  res.render('test', data);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

Please check https://github.com/HemingwayLee/sample-mustache-express
 and feel free to clone and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not include your html files in the public directory. Public Directory should contain only images, javascript and css files.

Though there are many ways to structure the node/express application, but you can find one good way using Express Generator.

http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

If you use this, it will create the app structure for you which clearly explains how you should keep you static files.