# How can I convert my templates from mustache to handlebars?

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, mustache, handlebars.java

I have templates that are mustache files that need to be converted to handlebars.
From doing research it looks like handlebars supports a lot but not all of the mustache functionality. Are there any tools that will allow me to automate this conversion?

- Mustache:https://mustache.github.io/
- Handlebars: https://handlebarsjs.com/
- Here are some differences between mustache and handlebars:
  [What are the differences between Mustache.js and Handlebars.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555820/what-are-the-differences-between-mustache-js-and-handlebars-js)

I am using these specific implementations of those templates:

- mustache: (Java) artifactId=jmustache https://github.com/samskivert/jmustache
- handlebars: (Java) artifactId=handlebars https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can automate converting mustache templates to handlebars templates with this python `mustache_to_handlebars` tool:
https://github.com/spacether/mustache_to_handlebars

One key differences is:

- #someTag in mustache covers these 3 use cases in handlebars: #if or #each or #with

And you can call it like:
`mustache_to_handlebars path_containing_mustache_files`